# Should I use getters or fields in JPA entity equals methods?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, equals

When writing an `equals` method for my JPA entity, should I access the fields directly, or should I go through the getters?

In other words, do I do this?

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(getIsbn(), book.getIsbn());
}
```

Or this?

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(isbn, book.isbn);
}
```

In this context, does it matter if I place the JPA annotations on the fields or on the getters? Also, does it matter if I use `FetchType.LAZY` (I imagine it would)? I read somewhere that lazy fields aren't materialized if you access by field and the annotation is placed on the getter (they'll remain `null` or empty), but does it happen when the annotation is placed on the field?

Does the behaviour differ between Hibernate and other vendors?

I googled, and even opened a book, but I'm kind of a JPA noob and I couldn't find a definitive answer to this question (although I did notice that experts tend to use getters in their blogs, such as [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)).

Answer (score 1):

`.equals` is a method defined inside the entity class. For this, there is no reason to use any `getters` since even fields with private access modifiers are accessible directly from methods of the same class.

> Also, does it matter if I use FetchType.LAZY (I imagine it would)?

Yes technically it would matter since you must have the session of entityManager open during invocation of `equals` for a lazy field otherwise the much known error of `LazyInitializationException` would occur. But because spring boot works with default of `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` it short-circuits this error as it keeps the session open until the response is handled to the user.

So if you use `Spring-Boot` and you don't have any customization yourself like `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` it should not matter if you use FetchType.Lazy or not for evaluation of `equals`.

Comment: Does it still work if I put an annotation with `FetchType.LAZY` on the getter, and I use fields directly in `equals`? (I've added this edge case to the question)

Comment: @jqno this has to do with the vendor. Hibernate for example requires from you to define the accessor type if you have getters and setters defined using `@Access` since having getters and setters would by default get picked by hibernate to access the information. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_overriding_the_default_access_strategy

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Hibernate will use getters and setters to initialize lazy fields, even if I place the annotations on the fields, unless I specify otherwise using `@Access`? Because in that case it seems safer to use getters in equals, if I'm dealing with lazy fields, right?

Comment: @jqno if I can understood the doc of hibernate correctly it means that if getters/setters are defined by default it will use those. To override this you must specify with `Access` that you want to read from fields directly

Comment: So, concluding... using fields is ok, unless the field has `FetchType.LAZY` and no `@Access` is used to override the behavior, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, proposed implementation:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(getIsbn(), book.getIsbn());
}
```

may violate `symmetric` contract of `#equals` method as soon as you start creating successors of the `Book` class:

- for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

At second, lazy-loading (`FetchType.LAZY`) does not work for `@Basic` fields in HBN by default: in order to make it work you need to enable [bytecode enhancements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html) (IMO, it makes sense for `@Lob` fields only).

And, at third, using fields to implement `#equals` **is NOT OK**, consider following code:

```
Book ref = session.load(Book.class, id);
Book book = Hibernate.unproxy(ref);
assertThat(book).isEqualTo(ref);
```

The problem is you may encounter proxy objects (instances of `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy`), which have the same fields as entity class has, but all of those fields are nulls:

[image]

Comment: So with Hibernate proxies, the fields are always null, but the getters will give the correct value? Do you have a link that explains how these proxies work?