Id public field sometimes null
I experience a strange behavior of the @Id field content in my app.
My entities are straight-forward:
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseObj {

  @Id
  public Long id;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " [id=" + id + ", version=" + version + "]";
  }
}

@Entity
public class Person extends BaseObj {}

When I do a complex Criteria Query and iterate through the Person objects:
persons.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach( p -> log.info(p + ", id = " + p.id + "/" + p.getId()) );

The log output looks like so:
Person [id=4589025417, version=41], id = 4589025417/4589025417
... 100 lines skipped ....
Person [id=6237623373, version=11], id = 6237623373/6237623373
Person [id=6393840242, version=6], id = 6393840242/6393840242 
Person [id=6524677164, version=5], id = null/6524677164       

as you can see the very last element of the list has the null id-field, but it's getter as well as toString() method both provided proper values.
Smells like a proxy problem to me.
What am I missing?

entities where you see nulls are proxies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74730796/3426309

they are all proxies
